# Call of duty: bo3 bullets taking so long to be counted as hits

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

On multiplayer on bo3 If i use the kuda or the hvk-30 for example, I would go and shoot someone but it seems to take 0.5-1.5 seconds for the hitmarkers to appear. Is this my internet being slow or teryarch's servers being slow and laggy. By the way my ping is 20-50ms and my ps4 is wireless. (I cant use Ethernet before you ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would most likely be your internet. Though you may have good ping, you may have issues connecting to the player who is designated as the host of the lobby. Try finding a new session. If your problem is consistent, try contacting Activision Support on Twitter.

Comment: Ok i think it may the host sometimes it is instant thanks for the help.